# If you knew how bad things were... or If you knew how bad things are

Tags: conditionals

Which one is correct and why?

> If you knew how bad things *were*, you would not go on vacation right now.

or

> If you knew how bad things *are*, you would not go on vacation right now.

This is assuming that "things" are actually bad right now (that's not up for discussion).

Comment: I think which is most appropriate would depend on the context.

Comment: and what about the context would make either option appropriate?

Comment: The first version is a perfectly natural example of ***backshifting***, as in *What did you say your name **was**?* (where clearly the speaker isn't normally suggesting your name might have changed since you last gave it out).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [To tell the name of a person I met in the past.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/262997/to-tell-the-name-of-a-person-i-met-in-the-past) Also [I asked + present/past tense](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/244114/i-asked-present-past-tense), and doubtless others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct, were is more formal, both can be used to refer to the present

Comment: I don't think there's any reason to suggest that ***were*** is more "formal". In other contexts, ***failing*** to backshift is certainly more ***unlikely*** and more ***literal***, but that's not really related to the concept of "formal language".

Comment: Agreed with FF here. Absolutely nothing formal about _were_ – if anything, I’d say the backshifted version sounds slightly less thought-through and thus more colloquial. I would consider the present to be more logically valid in this case (but not in “What did you say your name was?”, where backshifting is by far the more natural and logical option).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback :)